# Remove Angular Material pagination on responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive

Can i remove the pagination of my tab generated with Angular material on mobile only ??

I'm working on Angular 6 and using last version of material.

Thx!

Comment: you mean this? https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CDK Layout](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) to detect screen sizes inline with Angular Material breakpoints to conditionally set the `MatTableDataSource` paginator. This example assumes you would want to set a mobile "breakpoint" of 600px, but you can adjust to any px width you would need:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';    

@Component({
  selector: 'table-pagination-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-pagination-example.html',
})
export class TablePaginationExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  isLargeScreen: boolean = false;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([
      '(min-width: 600px)'
    ]).pipe(
      tap(result => this.isLargeScreen = result.matches)
    ).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.matches) {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      } else {
        this.dataSource.paginator = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then conditionally style `mat-paginator` using `ngStyle`. We use `ngStyle` instead something like `*ngIf` as that could effect `ViewChild` finding the `MatPaginator`:

```
<mat-paginator [ngStyle]="{display: isLargeScreen ? 'block' : 'none'}" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdekcy-xk9fly) demonstrating only activating the paginator for the respective `MatTableDataSource` only when media is **Tablet** or **Web**.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: You can also use flex-layout's fxHide.xs in the mat-paginator and remove isLargeScreen variable.